# How can I programmatically enable clean URLs during a SimpleTest?

Tags: 7, testing

How can I enable clean URLs from the SimpleTest [setUp()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--simpletest--drupal_web_test_case.php/function/DrupalUnitTestCase%3a%3asetUp/7) method?

Which .htaccess will be used during a simpletest?  I needed to make modifications to RewriteBase to get clean URL's working on the 'non-testing environment', will they carry over to the test environment or do I need to modify .htaccess in setUp() as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a few tests and here is what I found.

Enable Clean URLs in setUp() method:

```
function setUp() {
    variable_set('clean_url', 1);
}
```

.htaccess from live site is used during SimpleTest.  Modifications are not required.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned code will work, If mod_rewrite mod for Apache is enabled.  http://drupal.org/node/134439 link will give more info about how to enable mod_rewrite. If it is enabled then it will read .htaccess from live site.